# Object-oriented Programming - need your help

Tags: oop, c++-cli

I try to realize a little game project to dive deeper into OO programming (winforms c++/cli).
I already started coding but now I´d like to make a re-design. 
For the beginning the game should consist of four parts like game-engine, user interface, highscore and playground. Heres a little (non-UML-conform) class diagramm to visualize my purposes

[image: Class diagram]

Would this be the right way? 
In my eyes the game engine is responsible to control the game sequences (state machine?) and exchanges information betweens all other classes.

I appreciate any help!

EDIT:

so it´s a really simple game, no big deal! here´s a link of what I made by now:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-2595287/conways_project.exe.html
(no virus :) but I guess you need .NET framwork to get it work)

Comment: You should design first and then program a game. Also, is this game in a console, in 2D, 3D..?

Comment: It sounds you are more in search of existing example games. Game development generally driven by performance requirements, not the beauty of the design.

Comment: Hey how did you make this awesome diagram?

Comment: @Dummy00001: What do you mean by "game development generally driven by performance requirements, not the beauty of the design"? To have the best available performance one needs to design the application properly.

Comment: @Alerty: To have the best available performance one need (1) not to overdesign and (2) know bottlenecks of OS and HW (hardware). From knowing how OS and HW works, you create design which tries to exploit advantages and avoid the bottlenecks. You do NOT create a design and try to map it later onto OS/HW services - that likely to fail in the end.

Comment: @Dummy00001: I never said to over-design. One can have a beautiful design and have the best available performance. You can make miracles with OOP and generic programming in C++. Anyway, it is hardly possible to create a performant game without putting some thought into the design. Just have a look in any major project that it be for a game or not and you will see that people do take some time for the design. UML is there for a reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Unfortunately, your current design sucks :)*

I won't say what I will suggest is actually the best solution available, because in game design there is generally "no best" solution, but still I think it would make you think appropriately.

*Larger UML [here.](http://yuml.me/1924128b)*

[alt text http://yuml.me/1924128b](http://yuml.me/1924128b)

*Let's say you have your basic class `Game`. It's something abstract class, that wraps all your game logics and works as a sort of Swiss knife.*

You should create two another classes - `UI` and `State` (which, obviously, encapsulate game UI operations and store current game state). Let your `Game` class hold `UI` and `State` instances.

Now, your `Game` class should have basic methods to control your game. They could be plain `render(...)` and `update(...)` methods and this part is actually a bit tricky. If your game is real-time, you would have to update your state every Y milliseconds, so your `update(...)` should be called in a loop.

If your game isn't actually real-time, your updates should happen only when user does something or you *actually know* that you need to change something. You could implement a message queue here and `update(...)` call would simply flush all those messages.

Now, the `render(...)` method. Create some class and call it `Backend` - let this class encapsulate all your drawing possibilities. *There is one really cool thing here - you could let your `Backend` be an abstract superclass and create some **concrete** backends, which derive from `Backend`. And that would actually give you an opportunity to switch your `Backends` with simple code manipulations.*

After that, you should pass your `Backend` instance to your `render(...)` method, which would do appropriate drawing and it's logic could be written the following way:

```
foreach (const Object& object, game_state) {
   object->render(backend); // Or something like that
}
```

The last thing to mention, your game state. You could have a plain structure to hold all your current objects, score, etc, etc. Let every object access that `GameState` structure and everything will be fine.

*Actually, there are many things to think about, if you wish to, I could write more about this game design approach and share some tricks :)*

Comment: I would add that depending on what the OP is doing (console game, 3D game, etc.), it could be important to manage a window (initializing the window, errors, closing the window). Also, if this is in real time and in 2D or 3D (DirectX, OpenGL, etc.) it is important to have a constant FPS.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Game Engine' would probably be considered more of a 'Math Library.'  You might want to insert another object in between 'Game' and the other Server Classes that 'Delegates' the requirements of 'Game' to the Server Classes and call that 'Game Engine'.

Also maybe 'High Score' and 'Playground' could be combined into a Class which represents 'Game State' and port that directly to 'Game.'  'Playground' could be a Server Class which encapsulates any code to do the actual presenting of said background where this would usually represent a 'Rendering Class.'

IMHO